# Dreamweaver CS5.5 Mac OS X main CONFIGURATION folder deleted

Tags: macos, mac, dreamweaver, adobe-cs5

So I had a problem with Dreamweaver telling me that there is something wrong with a file so I went to Google to fix my problem but instead of deleting the configuration folder inside the en_US folder, I deleted the main one (which is important and should never be deleted) so now Dreamweaver is telling me "Dreamweaver is unable to locate the menus.xml file and cannot rebuilt it from backup. You may need to reinstall Dreamweaver" is there a solution for my problem? I am trying to recover my deleted folders from the trash. And btw before deleting the configuration folder I placed a copy of it on my desktop but somehow it turned out to be empty!

Answer (score 0):

Well - as it says, you should reinstall Dreamweaver. You might also be able to copy the files from another PC where Dreamweaver is installed.
You might want to try data recovery software, but the question would be if it would be worth the work. Reinstalling will be faster and more reliable to actually work.

Comment: Would copying the file from another mac work even if it was an Adobe CC version? And is there any data recovery software you might suggest? I am going to try several options before reinstalling it.

Comment: I'm not that deep into Adobe software to know if files from a different version will work, you might simply try, if not, just delete them. I oversaw that you're using a Mac, so sorry, no experience with any good data restore software.